# Cannot read property 'F_OK' of undefined in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I'm trying to use ExcelJS in NestJS. For some reason, I can not open xlsx file.

exceljs uses this code for checking if file exists

```
  fs: {
    exists: function exists(path) {
      return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        console.log(path);
        fs.access(path, fs.constants.F_OK, function (err) {
          resolve(!err);
        });
      });
    }
  },
```

that code returns Cannot read property 'F_OK' of undefined. Console.log on line 4 returns path I send it correctly

However, if I try to access the same file form my service with this code

```
    fs.access(this.file, fs.constants.F_OK | fs.constants.W_OK, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(
                `${this.file} ${err.code === 'ENOENT' ? 'does not exist' : 'is read-only'}`);
        } else {
            console.log(`${this.file} exists, and it is writable`);
        }
    });
```

That code returns "file.xlsx exists, and it is writable". What is the difference and why I can't read the same file with exceljs?

Comment: Can you show more code around the first snippet?

Comment: That code is from exceljs library you can take a look here https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/blob/85c680accc1c9fa1d28a91afee6de937414b571f/lib/utils/utils.js

Comment: https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/1492

Comment: Thanks for looking into it but, that's not the same issue. That issue revolves around React working in a browser that doesn't have access to nodeJS fs.

Comment: Can you show how you imported the `fs` library? I think it has to do with `fs/promises` and `fs`

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem.

The reason was because I was importing `fs/promises` and the `constants` are storaged in `fs`

Basically, you are trying to get the `constants` from a place where they were not declared.

This is how I solved:

```js
import fsp from 'fs/promises'
import fs from 'fs'

await fsp.access(testDir, fs.constants.F_OK);
```

You can see that for `access` I use `fsp.access` and for the `constants` `fs.constants.F_OK`

Comment: it solved the Issue for me but the problem is also solved by require rather than import
if you require('fs') then the constant is found under fs.F_OK